# PHP form sending duplicate emails

Tags: javascript, php, html, contact-form

I have a PHP contact form, it was working pretty well, but now my client says it's duplicating or even sending 4-5 times the contact email, my client says that it's taking too long to show the response on the webpage that tells user comment has been sent also, but I've tested it on my own server and everything works fine, is there any chance it may be a issue with their server? Here's my html:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="contacto.php" method="POST" novalidate>  
 <p>
    <label for="nombre">Tu nombre completo</label>
 </p>
 <p>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, llena todos los campos')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="correo">Tu e-mail</label>
 </p>
 <p>
    <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="mail@tucorreo.com" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, llena todos los campos')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
 </p>
 <p>
    <input type="text" name="asunto" id="asunto" placeholder="¿Por qué nos escribes?" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, llena todos los campos')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="aspirante">Nombre completo del aspirante</label>
 </p>
 <p>
    <input type="text" name="aspirante" id="aspirante" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, llena todos los campos')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="fecha">Fecha de nacimiento del aspirante</label>
 </p>
 <p>
    <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha" placeholder="dd/mm/aa" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, llena todos los campos')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="grado">Grado a cursar</label>
 </p>
 <p>
    <input type="text" name="grado" id="grado" placeholder="Grado a cursar" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, llena todos los campos')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="ciclo">Ciclo escolar</label>
 </p>
 <p>
    <input type="text" name="ciclo" id="ciclo" placeholder="Ej. 2016-2017" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, llena todos los campos')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="escuela">Escuela de procedencia</label>
 </p>
 <p>
    <input type="text" name="escuela" id="escuela" placeholder="Escuela de procedencia" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, llena todos los campos')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="ciudad">Ciudad de origen</label>
 </p>
 <p>
    <input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" placeholder="Ciudad de origen" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, llena todos los campos')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="comentario">Comentarios</label>
 </p>
 <p>
    <textarea type="text" name="comentario" id="comentario" placeholder="Déjanos saber tus comentarios" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, llena todos los campos')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/></textarea>
 </p>
 <p class="submit">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
 </p>
</form>
```

And the JS validating the form. I've also included the disabled button attribute once it has been sent:

```
<script>
/* Forma Contacto */
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {
    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();
    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
    $submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ),
    nombre_value = $form.find( 'input[name="nombre"]' ).val(),
    correo_value = $form.find( 'input[name="correo"]' ).val(),
    asunto_value = $form.find( 'input[name="asunto"]' ).val(),
    aspirante_value = $form.find( 'input[name="aspirante"]' ).val(),
    fecha_value = $form.find( 'input[name="fecha"]' ).val(),
    grado_value = $form.find( 'input[name="grado"]' ).val(),
    ciclo_value = $form.find( 'input[name="ciclo"]' ).val(),
    escuela_value = $form.find( 'input[name="escuela"]' ).val(),
    ciudad_value = $form.find( 'input[name="ciudad"]' ).val(),
    comentario_value = $form.find( 'textarea[name="comentario"]' ).val(),
    url = $form.attr('action');

    if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
        // the form is not valid
        // show some nice errors here
        $submit.text('Llena todos los campos');
        return false;
    }else{
        /* Send the data using post */
        var posting = $.post( url, { 
            nombre: nombre_value,
            correo: correo_value,
            asunto: asunto_value,
            aspirante: aspirante_value,
            fecha: fecha_value,
            grado: grado_value,
            ciclo: ciclo_value,
            escuela: escuela_value,
            ciudad: ciudad_value,
            comentario: comentario_value,
        });

        posting.done(function( data ){
            /* Put the results in a div */
            $( "#contactResponse" ).html(data);

            /* Change the button text. */
            $submit.text('Enviado');
            /* Disable the button. */
            $submit.attr("disabled", true);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

And finally my PHP:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "contacto@mail.com";
$EmailTo = "clientmail@mail.com";
$Subject = "Nuevo comentario en el website";
$nombre = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['nombre'])); 
$correo = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['correo'])); 
$asunto = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['asunto']));
$aspirante = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['aspirante'])); 
$fecha = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['fecha'])); 
$grado = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['grado'])); 
$ciclo = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['ciclo'])); 
$escuela = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['escuela'])); 
$ciudad = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['ciudad'])); 
$comentario = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['comentario'])); 

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Nombre: ";
$Body .= $nombre;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "E-mail: ";
$Body .= $correo;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Asunto: ";
$Body .= $asunto;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Nombre del aspirante: ";
$Body .= $aspirante;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Fecha de Nacimiento: ";
$Body .= $fecha;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Grado a cursar: ";
$Body .= $grado;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Ciclo escolar: ";
$Body .= $ciclo;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Escuela de procedencia: ";
$Body .= $escuela;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Ciudad de origen: ";
$Body .= $ciudad;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Comentario: ";
$Body .= $comentario;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
    echo "<h2>¡Gracias! Recibimos tu mensaje</h2>";
}
else{
    echo "<h2>Lo sentimos, hubo un error, inténtalo nuevamente</h2>";
}
?>
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? As i said, I've tested it to my server and everything works perfectly, but not on my client server. Any help?

Comment: Check client php version and email configured or not onserver

Comment: If you don't redirect to another page, if the user refreshes the page, form is submitted again. Pay attention to this. However if this is not the problem you can use an external library to send mails like https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

I think basically there are two things to answer. (1) Your code might have errors that allow a user to submit the same form multiple times. (2) How are e-mails sent out by PHP scripts (client complains that page is slow).

(1) I reviewed your JavaScript code and from reading it I believe that you should lock the submit button until the evaluation state of the form is clear. You do already have the following line:

```
$submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' )
```

Immediately after retrieving the form values through (I assume jQuery) you could do the following:

```
$submit.prop('disabled', true);
```

Of course if it becomes clear that the form is invalid and the user is allowed to submit again you need to do:

```
$submit.prop('disabled', false);
```

Please be aware the above code works with jQuery 1.6+ if you use jQuery 1.5 the proper code is:

```
$submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$submit.removeAttr('disabled');
```

You have similar code a little later in your script. It is hard for me to debug this since only code fragments are available such that I cannot debug it in a real browser.

(2) In your PHP you use the `mail()` function which relies on the server systems SMTP / sendmail configuration to drop of e-mail. I assume that in the case of your test system you have a local mail system running. When the PHP `mail()` function sends mail on your machine it can directly drop mail on `localhost`. In the production environment however it is very likely that a central mail server with authentication and everything is in place. This means that the `mail()` function executes an elaborate process of connecting to the SMTP server, perhaps authenticating to it, then dropping of the mail body and waiting for a server response. The server will only respond if it successfully queued your e-mail message in one of its out-queues. This can also take some time if the mail server is und load. Long story short talk to your client about this scenario and try to find ways to mitigate this (in our hosting we have local mail forwarders on all machines `SSMTP` which is very helpful).